# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. while creating a new stored procedure in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012

I am getting `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'`. while doing drop and create for a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012. This error only comes for this stored procedure only while I can drop and create other stored procs just as usual. The thing is that it has now dropped the stored procedure and won't create now.

Any idea?

Comment: Does your sproc contain a reference to a remote object (a four-part name like `server.database.schema.table`)? These objects need to have their schemas checked while the procedure is created, and if authentication goes wrong, you're presented with this unhelpful message. You may need to recreate the linked server definition (`sp_dropserver`, `sp_addlinkedserver`).

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: @T-Heron Yes, we figured it out. In our case, it was due to permissions issues with respect to the user.